# Android Expandable list view with customarrayadapter

Tags: android

I am working on `expandablelistview`. Each row of this group view has a two images. I need a functionality like this:

On clicking one -> Expand and collapse the group

On clikcing other -> do something else.

I know that we can use 
`setOngrouplistener()` and `Onclicklistener`

the problem is `onclicklistner` gives the group position.
Please help to solve this problem.